# Admissible relations in a Banach algebra

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-algebras, locally-convex-spaces

Suppose that $\mathbb{C}\left\langle x, y \right\rangle = R$  is a free (associative and unital) algebra and $f \in R$. I wonder whether there exists a (unital) Banach algebra $A$ and a non-zero pair $(a, b)$, $a,b \in A$, such that $f(a, b)=0$ in $A$. I will call such $f$ admissible. In other words, I aim to describe all possible relations which can occur in a Banach algebra.

For example, using the notion of spectrum of an element, one is able to deduce that the relation $xy - yx - 1$ cannot occur in a non-trivial Banach algebra, so it is not admissible.

At the moment I know only one approach to the problem: for a fixed $f \in R$ we can consider the quotient algebra $R_f := \mathbb{C}\left\langle x, y \right\rangle / I$, where $I$ is a two-sided ideal, generated by $f$, and take its Arens-Michael envelope. Then it is easy to see that $f$ is admissible $\iff$ the Arens-Michael envelope $\widehat{R_f}$ is non-zero. We also know that in this case the Arens-Michael envelope commutes with the quotient in a following way:
$$
\widehat{R_f} \simeq \hat{R} / \overline{i_R(I)},
$$
where $\hat{R} \simeq \mathcal{F}_2$, the Arens-Michael algebra of noncommutative power series, and $i_R : \mathbb{C}\left\langle x, y \right\rangle \rightarrow \mathcal{F}_2$ is the natural inclusion. So, the problem can reduced to the problem of describing maximal two-sided, closed ideals of $\mathcal{F}_2$, which is, unfortunately, still quite difficult.

Maybe there is another, more effective approach to this problem?

Comment: What are other examples of non-admissible nonconstant polynomials?

Comment: I think that the example I provided can be modified as follows: suppose that $f \in \mathbb{C}[x]$ and $g \in \mathbb{C}[y]$. Then the element $f(x)g(y)-g(y)f(x)-1$ defines a non-admissible relation as well. Unfortunately, at the moment, I can't come up with more interesting and less trvial examples.

Comment: Are you familiar with the C*-theory of relations? https://arxiv.org/abs/0807.4988

Comment: This is a fascinating question, and I would be very interested to see any further progress. Did you mention this problem to my colleagues when you met them at the Oulu conference?

Comment: Yes, In fact, I remember asking Niels Laustsen about this. If my memory serves me right, he mentioned that due to Barry Johnson there is a description of admissible relations in $\mathcal{B}(H)$ for a (separable) Hilbert space $H$. However, I couldn't find any reference of this, that is why I didn't include this in the original post.